# Specific things with type cast operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(int a):a(a){}
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    operator A()
    {
        return 10;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    cout << ((A)b).a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and prints `10` in visual studio. But in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Other_operators) next to cast operator I found this sentence: `Note: for user-defined conversions, the return type implicitly and` **necessarily** `matches the operator name.`

Now how the code above works? Is this feature of visual studio? Or it shoud match only implicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator A()` is a user-defined conversion operator.  It's job is to return an `A` by-value when you cast a `B` to an `A`.

Your `operator A()` function is returning a literal integer value, `10`.  But `operator A` needs to return an `A`, so `A`'s convert constructor is called with the value `10`.  This results in a temporary `A` being constructed.  You are then accessing `.a` on this temporary object, and inserting the value of `.a` in to the stream, which results in you seeing `10` on the screen.

EDIT

When wiki said that the converstion operator "implicitly" returned an `A`, it meant that you don't have to specify the return type in the function declarion.  It's always an `A` and there's nothing you can do about it.

When wiki said that it "necesarrily" returned an `A` it meant that it can't return anything but an `A`.  It can't even return anything convertible to an `A`.  It has to return an `A` exactly.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. My question is "if name of return type of cast operator should implicitly or necessarily (which in my opinion same as explicitly) match to name of operator?"

Answer (score 1):

`B::operator A()` implicitly returns an `A`.  Therefore `return 10` is implicitly equivalent to `return (A)10`, or `return A(10)`.

Comment: And what about **necessarilly**? Is this typo or I understanding its meaning incorrect?

Comment: @Mihran: It means that it is necessary, by the definition of a cast overload, for the return type to match the operator name.